# When one can use LAST in the continuous form?

Tags: stative-verbs

TO LAST is usually stative, so it's usually used in the present/past simple. But I am sure there are exceptions. Do these make sense?

> This speech is lasting longer than it usually would.
>
> This hot weather is lasting a long time.

If we used the present simple in the above sentences, would it twist the meaning to a point of the sentences being wrong?

> This speech lasts longer than it usually would.
>
> This hot weather lasts a long time.

Here is a sentence form a grammar

**She’s sleeping on the veranda while this hot weather lasts.**

Is it correct to use continuous?

**She’s sleeping on the veranda while this hot weather is lasting.**

Answer (score 1):

**The verb "to last" is not stative** - it is a dynamic verb, similar to "endure" or "withstand".

So it is used in a continuous form just like any verb of that type.

***Public enthisiasm for for the present government is not lasting as long as many expected.***

***The food supplies are lasting longer than I expected.***

Comment: If it's dynamic, why is it presented in a dictionary in the present simple: "Is your mother at sea yet?" B: "Yes, her cruise lasts several weeks."?

Comment: @user1425 dynamic verbs are  used in *any* tense: present, present continuous, past, past continuous etc.  *We run--we are running, we ran---we were running*

Comment: @user1425 Dynamic verbs are not always used in a continuous form. For example consider the verb "to walk". I can use it simply - "I walk to school every day", or continuously "At 8.30am I am usually walking to school".  A stative verb is one which expresses a state or condition - such as "own" as in "She owns the house at the end of the road", or "know" as in "Although he is only five he knows the names of all the planets".  Many verbs can be used both statively and dynamically, or can be forced in some circumstances one way or the other.

Comment: OK. Why is it that in this dictionary example they don't use the continuous form? "Is your mother at sea yet?" B: "Yes, her cruise lasts several weeks."? It's not that this cruise is a habitual cruise which she goes on regularly.

Comment: @user1425 But there would be absolutely nothing wrong,  indeed it would be  perfectly idiomatic, to say "She has just returned from a cruise lasting several weeks" or "The food supplies are lasting longer than I expected". These are everyday uses of "last" in a continuous form. Believe me, I am a native speaker.

Comment: "She has just returned from a cruise lasting several weeks"  - has no present continuous by the way. This would be in continuous "Yes, her cruise is lasting several weeks."

Comment: Do you mean that either is correct? "Is your mother at sea yet?" B: "Yes, her cruise lasts several weeks."? OR "Yes, her cruise is lasting several weeks."

Comment: @user1425  There are plenty of more commonly used examples of the continuous verb "to last". e.g. ***This performance is lasting longer than its predecessor.  Those flowers which were picked a week ago are lasting well***.

Comment: "*Her cruise **lasts** several weeks*" means, the cruise **is scheduled to last** several weeks. "*Her cruise **is lasting** several weeks*" means the cruise **is currently lasting** several weeks -- regardless of what the schedule says. It's an odd construction, and I'd have to think hard to come up with a context where it made good sense.

Comment: WS2, believe it or not, that's why I ask questions because it's not as clear as it may seem

Comment: gotube, but it should be "The cruise has been lasting several weeks" otherwise "is lasting" means it is going to last which is also a kind of schedule

Comment: @gotube I would agree that there are different circumstances in which one would use "is lasting" versus "lasts". One would opt for the former if, e.g. something was going on for longer than expected -***this wretched meeting is lasting longer than I had planned to stay***. However in advance someone may have told you ***the meeting lasts for an hour***.  But such differences are the case with any use of the continuous. It will always reflect different semantics.

Comment: @user1425 No, as WS2 has now also explained, "is lasting" is only used when something is lasting some time *other than what's scheduled*. It describes an ongoing situation, not necessarily what is expected to happen.